# Как объединить foreach и for?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Добрый день
Есть такой кусок кода:

```
$result = array_unique($array);
$all = count($result);
for($i=1; $i<$all; $i++)
{
    foreach ($result as $key => $value)
    {

    }
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, "UPDATE `21.02.18` SET teachers_processed=? WHERE id=$i");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $value);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); //выполнение подготовленного запроса
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); //закрываем запрос
}
```

Как это всё объединить? Сейчас этот код работает, но не так как надо. Помогите пожалуйста :)

В итоге нужно, что бы в базе обновлялся столбик *teachers_processed* , и чтобы обновления в базу заносились начиная с первого id

Comment: Доброе утро. Как надо, чтобы он работал? Гадать на кофейной гуще? И ещё, использовать запросы к базе в цикле не очень хорошая идея.

Comment: И вы как то странно используете подготовку запросов. _Никогда_ не подставляйте значения переменных непосредственно в текст запроса. `$i` в запросе следует заменить на `?` и использовать для этого параметра то же bind_param. Тогда можно будет вынести prepare за цикл, а внутри делать только bind и execute.

Comment: @Mike можно пример ?

Comment: какой пример. у вас и так пример написан. я не предлагаю использовать ни одной функции, которой нет в вашем текущем примере. Вы же можете заменить `$i` в запросе на вопросительный знак ? И поправить `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'si', $value,$i);` что бы оба параметра привязывались. Ну и вынести после этого prepare до цикла, а close после

Comment: И что то мне подсказывает что вам цикл for вообще не нужен. можно переменную $i сделать 1 перед началом foreach и внутри делать $i++

Comment: Mike дал верный ответ. Всё работает, спасибо большое :)

Answer (score 0):

Писал с головы, могут быть ошибки

```
$teachers_unique_processed = array_unique($teachers_processed);
//Здесь заменяем ключи масива начиная от 1. Это избавит от наличия счетчика
$teachers_unique_processed = array_combine(range(1, count($teachers_unique_processed)), $teachers_unique_processed);

//Здесь формируем один запрос. Он будет выполняться значительно быстрее чем много отдельных.
$update_query = "UPDATE `table` SET ";
foreach($teachers_unique_processed as $id => $value){
  $update_query .= "WHEN `id`='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($id) . "' THEN '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($value) . "' ";
}

$update_query = " WHERE `id` iN (" . implode(',', array_keys($teachers_unique_processed)) . ")";
mysqli_query($update_query) or die(mysqli_error());
```